# Forward emails to imap folders of a central account

Tags: email, imap

Hope thats not a to silly question, I have very little understanding of email stuff and always avoided it.

So what I like to do is have some domain with different emails setup but all emails should end up into a central account but organised into folders

Like

```
something@example.com
somethingelse@example.com
```

Central IMAP Mail accounts folders.

```
/something/*
/somethingelse/*
```

If I simply forward this mails this wont work I guess.

**Edit:** Ok i get more specific now

So to get more specific I am **not** using gmail but my email provider supports filters for sender, reciever, subject, copy to.
But how do I detect if a mail was forwarded? I came to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735293/forwarded-email-detection).

How is this about DNS forwarding? What is the difference between just setting DNS to my email and "real" a real email forwarding service? Just read about MX record and that they are only for SMTP so this is only for sending email?

So I need to have some service to forward my mails for my domain not just DNS records? Is there generally something that send with this forwarded mails rather then the header stuff mentioned in the question above because I can't(server side)/want to setup strange header filters.

Comment: Which MTA do you use? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...] Which IMAP server do you use?

Comment: I don't know what MTA means and I am using a public mail provider not a self hosted IMAP server.

Comment: @Wayne'sWorld: An MTA is a Mail Transfer Agent, which is a program that handles email. Common examples would be Postfix or Microsoft Exchange.

Comment: Depending on how this problem should be solved, the solution is largely dependent on the tools your provider gives you on the server side or the email client you're using. Sometimes the provider may have a setup that allows what you ask to be configured directly in a web interface. A more common approach is to have all email addresses routed to the same mailbox. Then you set up filters in your email client that moves the emails into the specific folder. Although, with IMAP, it would usually be preferable to have a server-side solution. The given answers already mention these though.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the mail provider[s] you're working with as the source mailboxes will need to forward their mail to the destination, and the destination mail provider would have to support rules/filters on incoming mail to have it flow into the proper accounts.

I know GMail supports both of these:

- Forwarding: Settings > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > Forwarding
- Message Filtering/Tagging/Folders: Settings > Filters

Each has instructions already available during the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If something and somethingelse forward to the same email account you can setup some client side filtering that will deposit the mail in the appropriate folder based on the 'To' header when you check your email. Also, depending on your what your mail provider uses you may be able to contact them to see what options they have available. They might have a web interface to set something up or they might be able to install a [Sieve](http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/sieve/charter/) script for you.